# Collision Detection in love2d(lua)

Tags: lua, collision-detection, game-physics, game-development, love2d

I am doing a game development course by cs50 where Colton Ogden teaches love2d which is in lua. I am facing a problem in collision detection. The below code/logic works fine when the object is not rotating example love.graphics.draw(texture, x, y, r).

Here x and y is some value and r(rotation is 0). Value of x and y keeps on changing.

```
function Projectile:collides(target)
        if self.x > target.x + target.width or target.x > self.x + self.width then
            return false
        end
    
        if self.y > target.y + target.height or target.y > self.y + self.height then
            return false
        end
    
        return true
end
```

But the above code doesn't work for target which is rotating i.e., r has some value which keeps on changing.

Below is how i am rotating an object.

```
function Meteor:init(speed)
    self.r = math.random(-1, 1)
end

function Meteor:update(dt)
    if self.r > 0 then
        self.r = self.r + math.pi/9 * dt
    elseif self.r < 0 then
        self.r = self.r - math.pi/9 * dt
    else
        self.r = self.r    
    end
    
    if self.y < VIRTUAL_HEIGHT + 110 then
        self.y = self.y + self.speed * dt
    else
        self.remove = true
    end    
end

function Meteor:render()
    love.graphics.drawLayer(self.meteor, self.type, self.x, self.y, self.r)
end
```

Comment: provide more info. what do you mean with does not work? any own debugging attempts? you could print what's going on, which of the conditions are met...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier and sufficient to just approximate an object's collision. In LÖVE you can specify the texture offset in [`love.graphics.draw()`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.draw). Let the texture rotate at its center and see if an approximation works.

If you really need rectangles, which are not axis aligned, you may want to use a collision library. [HardonCollider](https://vrld.github.io/HardonCollider/) works perfect.

If you plan on adding physics too, then the [LÖVE physics module](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.physics) makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

As @Luke100000 wrote LÖVE has already a collision detection in love.physics implemented.
Read and try: https://love2d.org/wiki/Tutorial:PhysicsCollisionCallbacks
For a zero gravity world i use for example...

```
function love.load()
local meter=4.5
love.physics.setMeter(meter)
ZeroGravity=love.physics.newWorld(0,0,true)
ZeroGravity:setCallbacks(Hit,Release,preSolve,postSolve) -- <Collision Callbacks>
end
```

And for example the "Hit" callback function...

```
-- <Collision Callback Functions>
Hit=function(a,b)
a:getBody():setUserData(os.date('%H:%M:%S'))
b:getBody():setUserData(os.date('%H:%M:%S'))
a:getUserData():emit(256)
b:getUserData():emit(256)
return true
end
```

The particlesystem that emitting 256 parts at "Hit" is assigned to the fixture in userdata of an physics body at creation...

```
function addAsteroid(x,y,r,kind)
local body=love.physics.newBody(ZeroGravity,x,y,kind)
local shape=love.physics.newCircleShape(r)
local fixture=love.physics.newFixture(body,shape,.01)
fixture:setUserData(psystem:clone()) -- Particlesystem for emitting
fixture:setDensity(1)
fixture:setFriction(1)
fixture:setRestitution(1)
--fixture:setFilterData(1,1,-1)
fixture:getUserData():start()
return body
end
```

A particle system can be very complex but it is worth for learning it.
Here i give you an example of mine that works with quads...

```
-- planets.lua
fields=1
quads={love.graphics.newImage("planets.png")
}
local assets={x=0,y=0,size=.1,time=-1,
[1]=love.graphics.newQuad(138,33,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[2]=love.graphics.newQuad(505,37,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[3]=love.graphics.newQuad(871,21,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[4]=love.graphics.newQuad(1238,22,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[5]=love.graphics.newQuad(1606,15,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[6]=love.graphics.newQuad(1974,11,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[7]=love.graphics.newQuad(1976,349,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[8]=love.graphics.newQuad(136,382,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[9]=love.graphics.newQuad(504,379,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[10]=love.graphics.newQuad(871,366,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[11]=love.graphics.newQuad(1236,362,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[12]=love.graphics.newQuad(19,724,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[13]=love.graphics.newQuad(1047,698,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[14]=love.graphics.newQuad(1376,687,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[15]=love.graphics.newQuad(1721,686,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[16]=love.graphics.newQuad(2042,684,300,300,quads[1]:getDimensions()),
[17]=love.graphics.newQuad(347,704,660,300,quads[1]:getDimensions())
}
pquads={x=0,y=0,size=1,time=-1}
for i=12,12 do table.insert(pquads,assets[i]) end -- recall
assets=empty
psystem=love.graphics.newParticleSystem(quads[1],72)
psystem:setBufferSize(4096)
psystem:setLinearAcceleration(-150,-150,150,150) -- Random movement in all directions.
psystem:setEmissionArea('ellipse',145,145,math.rad(math.random(360)),false)
psystem:setQuads(pquads)
psystem:setSpread(75)
--[[psystem:setColors({love.math.random(),
love.math.random(),
love.math.random(),
0.3},{love.math.random(),
love.math.random(),
love.math.random(),
0.6},{love.math.random(),
love.math.random(),
love.math.random(),
0.3})]]--
--psystem:setColors({1,0,0,1},{0,0,1,1},{1,0,0,1})
--psystem:setColors({0,0,1,1},{1,1,1,1},{1,1,0,1},{1,0,0,1})
psystem:setSizes(math.random()*.05,0)
--psystem:setSizes(.1,.2,.3,.4,.3,.2,.1)
psystem:setSizeVariation(0)
psystem:setEmitterLifetime(pquads.time)
psystem:setParticleLifetime(pquads.size*11)
psystem:setEmissionRate(pquads.size*.11)
psystem:setInsertMode('top')
-- psystem:setPosition(-150,-150)
```

The assets i am using i get from...
https://opengameart.org/art-search?keys=planets